# Linux headrers for 3.2.52-030252-generic-pae

Tags: kernel

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and want to install the headers. I ran

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

but I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.2.52-030252-generic-pae
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.2.52-030252-generic-pae'
```

Where are the headers for this particular kernel version located?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.52-030252-generic`

Comment: Why do you have that old a kernel with 14.04?

Comment: This kernels and headers are not supported. You can't install them from Ubuntu repositories. Unsupported kernels are off-topic.